# How to retrieve a image url from a list of dictionaries and display it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-imaging-library, urllib

I have a list of dictionaries containing data on products. Each product has one image url. The data looks very much like below. I wrote the code below and it works as intended but I'm pretty sure this can be done in one step by retrieving the url right from `items_dicts`. I instead used a dictionary comprehension to return a new dict `item_dict` given a specific `uniq_id` and then proceeded to retrieve the url from `item_dict`.

Data:

```
items_dicts = [
   {
      "uniq_id":"123987",
      "sku":"123",
      "name":"ABC",
      "cat":"DEF",
      "cat_tree":"A|B|C",
      "image_urls":"http://sitecom/image1.tif"
   },
    {
      "uniq_id":"987123",
      "sku":"987",
      "name":"GHI",
      "cat":"JKL",
      "cat_tree":"Z|Y|X",
      "image_urls":"http://sitecom/img/image2.tif"
   }
]
```

Code:

```
# import modules
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image

# Return a specific product dict and assign it to item_1
item_dict = {i['uniq_id'] : i for i in items_dicts}
item_1 = item_dict.get('987123', 'None')

# Retrieve img url from item_1 dict
# And save it as item_img.png
urllib.request.urlretrieve(item_1.get('image_urls'),"img.png")

# Open item img and display it
item_img = Image.open("img.png")
item_img.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

To get one specific value from your list of dicts, for example where `uniq_id` is 123987, you can use the following:

```
[x['image_urls'] for x in items_dicts if x['uniq_id'] == '123987']
```

---

I'm not sure about your exact intention, but you can get easily get a list of all URLs from your list of dicts by using a list comprehension:

```py
[x['image_urls'] for x in items_dicts]
```

Giving you:

```py
['http://sitecom/image1.tif', 'http://sitecom/img/image2.tif']
```

You can then take this list and display it as you need to.

Comment: I want to retrieve the URL for only one specific product using the `uniq_id` key.

Comment: @elideli If you know your `uniq_id` key beforehand, then you see my edited answer, it will return the URL you need.